# Is possible in Ada a discontinuous subtype definition?

Tags: ada

Let's suppose I have the following constants in order to define a subtype that only admits valid values within its range definition:

```
type Unsigned_4_T is mod 2**4;

valid_1   : constant Unsigned_4_T := 0;
valid_2   : constant Unsigned_4_T := 1;
invalid_1 : constant Unsigned_4_T := 2;
valid_3   : constant Unsigned_4_T := 3;
```

Now, I would like to define a subtype VALID_VALUES_T of Unsigned_4_T in a way that it only accepts the valid values using the constants valid_1, valid_2 and valid_3.

I have been trying to achieve that using a Static_Predicate but, when I declare a variable of the wanted subtype and I assign the invalid_1 value, there is no constraint nor compilation error as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AdaCore compiler requires you to enable assertions to generate the exception you need. Compile your program with the -gnata flag.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;
with System.Assertions; use System.Assertions;

procedure Main is
   type Unsigned is mod 2**4;
   subtype discontinuous is Unsigned with
     Static_Predicate => discontinuous in 0 | 1 | 3;
   Num : discontinuous;
begin
   for I in Unsigned'Range loop
      Num := I;
      Put_Line(Num'Image);
   end loop;
exception
   when E :Assert_Failure =>
      Put_Line("Invalid value assigned to Num: " & Exception_Message(E));
end Main;
```

The output of the program is:

```
    
 0
 1
Invalid value assigned to Num: Static_Predicate failed at main.adb:12
```

Comment: Another option is to add pragma Assertion_Policy(Check);

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that but I used                                            `Static_Predicate => discontinuous in valid_1 | valid_2 | valid_3;´                     
instead of `Static_Predicate => discontinuous in 0 | 1 | 3;´ Then I assigned the invalid constant to the "discontinuous" subtype and no error was being raised, I don't know if due to the subtyping or what

Comment: My problem was due to the -gnata flag, confirmed; the solution proposed by @AnhVo works ok too. In both cases, the errors are raised in execution, is it possible to detect them during compilation?

Comment: Assertions are checked by the at run-time. The SPARK tools can detect the errors through formal verification, but that is separate from compilation.

Comment: I am looking for the day that a compiler can do that. For now, it is the job of SPARK tools called GNAT Prover.

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment after accepting the answer, but trying `pragma Assertion_Policy (Static_Predicate => Check);` to enclose the cases where the compiler shall create an assertion is not working to me when I assign a value that is not included in the type definition, despite `pragma Assertion_Policy(Check);` works. Does anybody have the same problem?